# Sort a hash of hashes twice in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, hash

I have a hash with structure:

```
{"time_period" => {product_id = val"}}
```

For example,

```
{"This Month"  =>{2414=>12, 2601=>12, 2604=>6, 2624=>12, 2628=>12,
                  2647=>24, 2652=>6, 2659=>18, 2709=>24},
 "Last Month"  =>{511=>12, 2266=>12, 2414=>24, 2601=>12, 2607=>36, 2609=>60,
                  2611=>6, 2626=>36, 2647=>36, 2659=>18, 2699=>24, 2709=>12},
 "Last 30 Days"=>{2414=>24, 2601=>12, 2604=>6, 2607=>12, 2609=>12, 2611=>6, 2624=>12,
                  2626=>12, 2628=>12, 2647=>36, 2652=>6, 2659=>24, 2699=>12, 2709=>24}}
```

I display this as a table, with time periods as columns and each product_id as  one row with corresponding values from the hash.

If a user wants to sort that table by column "Last Month" how will I go about doing that ? So I want the keys in the "Last Month" array to be at the top of the table, and then those keys sorted by their values.

I don't want to convert this into an array because there will be a lot of 0 values for each product and memory usage would be huge if we increase time periods and products.

---

The hash is created like this:

```
overall_h = Hash.new 
timeperiods.each do |t| 
  overall_h[t] = Order.customer_filter(customer_id)
                      .valid_order.group_by_orde‌​r_products.sum_qty 
end
```

Comment: Depending on an order in a Hash is the wrong way to do this. Why not pairs like `[511, 12]`? That way they can be ordered. `hash.to_a` does the conversion.

Comment: When you say: "I display this as a table, with time periods as columns and each product_id as one row with corresponding values from the hash." Does this mean you have some empty cells?

Comment: @tadman `Hash#sort` will convert the hash to the nested Array structure you describe automatically, and return the pairs sorted by key.

Comment: It sounds like your requirements are at cross purposes with one another. If you have so much data that you can't hold it in memory, maybe you need to use a database.

Comment: @tompave, yes I do have a lot of empty cells.

Comment: @moveson - I am using a database. This page is needed when I want to display Top Products for a Customer (example : http://imgur.com/a/YS1tZ). But this page combines information from different tables like Orders - Order Products - Customer

Comment: Standard practice would be to do the sort in the database and limit your results to the number of records you want to display on screen.

Comment: Please post the code you use to query the database and the code to build the hash structure.

Comment: @HinamMehra you mention "page" – is this related to Rails or another web framework?

Comment: @Stefan - yes, this is related to Rails

Comment: @spickermann 
overall_h = Hash.new
timeperiods.each do |t|
    overall_h[t] = Order.customer_filter(customer_id).valid_order.group_by_order_products.sum_qty
end
Does this help?